# Ionic 2 consuming json issue

Tags: json, web-services, angular, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 and i couldn't consume a json. for some reason it throws an error.

Here is my updated code.

**sales-service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SalesService {
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
 }
retrieveSalesData() {
    return this.http.get("http://api.randomuser.me/?results=10");
 }
```

}

**sale.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-sale',
  templateUrl: 'sale.html',
  providers: [SalesService],
})
export class SalePage {
data:any;
  constructor(data: SalesService) {
    this.data=data.retrieveSalesData().subscribe(data =>{
              this.data=JSON.parse(data._body).results;
              console.log("Inside Subscribe (All Elements):"+ this.data);
              console.log("Inside Subscribe (Single Element):"+this.data[1].name.first);
            });
        console.log("Inside Constructor (All Elements):"+ this.data);
        console.log("Inside Constructor (Single Element):"+ this.data[1].name.first);
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
              console.log("Inside IonView (All Elements):"+ this.data);
              console.log("Inside IonView (Single Element):"+this.data[1].name.first);
  }
}
```

**sale.html** -- This is not the issue so i've commented the code

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-content padding>
<!--<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of data">
      <h2>{{item.name.first}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>-->
</ion-content>
```

**Here is my error:**

[image]

I think i found the issue, but don't know how to clear it. 
All elements are received in subscribe, but not in constructor and as well as in IonView. Please advise.

**Here is my ionic info**

[image]

Comment: please post your json structure

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @MohanGopi, i'm using an online web service for this question. please click this link, https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10

Comment: ngFor should be *ngFor right?

Comment: @RavinSinghD, if i use *ngFor i'm getting an unexpected token error. Please view this link (http://imgur.com/a/cFXGt). Maybe the version i'm using is a different one.

Comment: *ngFor="let item of items"  this is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer that's working for me.

This is what i did,

```
public data:Users[]=[];
  constructor(public pdata: SalesService) {
    pdata.retrieveSalesData().subscribe(data =>{
              JSON.parse(data._body).results.forEach(element => {
                this.data.push(
                  new Users(element.name.first)
                   );
              }); 
            });
  }

export class Users {
  name: string;
  constructor(_name: string) {
     this.name = _name;
  }
}
```

This works for me. If there is an alternative and elegant way. please feel free to update the answer. Thank you for all your time.

Answer (score 0):

change your sales-service.ts file like bleow

```
@Injectable()
export class SalesService {
salesData:any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    //this.http = http;
    this.salesData = [];
  }
retrieveSalesData() {
    this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
    .subscribe(salesData => {
      this.salesData = salesData.result;
    });
  }
}
```

inside your html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let person of data">
      <p>{{person.name.first}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I need to change the sales-service.ts as well right?

Comment: yes you have to change html and ts file as with my answer

Comment: instead of `.result` probably should change to `.salesData` if you want to loop through that.

Comment: @MohanGopi, If i change salesData to salesData.result (or results), i'm getting "undefined" when calling the service. and also still having binding issues. please see this http://imgur.com/a/9q5Ba

Comment: come to private chat

Answer (score 0):

I don't care of your **update1**.

I assume you get **response object** in **this.data** object.

If you are dealing with latest angular2 version, make sure you use **let** keyword instead of  **#** as show below,

```
<ion-item ngFor="let person of data">                   //<<<===here
      <p>{{person?.name.first}}</p>                     //<<<=== (?.) operator is used as you deal with async call.
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @micronyks, I tried your solution, I got no errors but no data is displayed on the view as well. http://imgur.com/yYc3Nj9.

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwoing

**sales-service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SalesService {
  salesData:any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
   this.http = http;
   this.salesData = null;
 }
retrieveSalesData() {
return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
}
}
```

**sale.ts**

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'page-sale',
 templateUrl: 'sale.html',
 providers: [SalesService]
})
export class SalePage {
data:any;
  constructor(private salesService: SalesService) {
     }
 ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.salesService.retrieveSalesData()
  .subscribe(salesData => {
     this.data= salesData;
   });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your app-scripts:

`npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest`

Their previous version was missing a JSON plugin which [they just added to the rollup process](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/pull/79/commits/838eeeb347c3b42350f6a4d1df8f52285d34d70f).